# Python script running out of memory

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, concurrency

The script below runs out of memory. I can see child processes staying at the same consumption, but the parent process seems to continuously increase the memory usage. I'm trying to understand why this is happening.

```
import concurrent.futures
import os
import pandas
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
from datetime import datetime

db_host = os.environ.get('DB_HOST')
db_port = os.environ.get('DB_PORT')
db_username = os.environ.get('DB_USERNAME')
db_password = os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD')
db_database = os.environ.get('DB_DATABASE')
engine_str = (create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{db_username}:{db_password}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{db_database}")
              .execution_options(stream_results=True))
engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{db_username}:{db_password}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{db_database}")


def process_chunk(chunk):
    with engine.connect() as con:
        for i in range(len(chunk)):
            row = dict(chunk.loc[i])
            new_row = {}
            for key in row:
                if key == "serial_no":
                    new_row["serial_number"] = row[key]
                elif key == "product_id":
                    new_row["product_id"] = row[key]
                else:
                    new_row["contract_" + key] = row[key]
            new_row["contract_inserted_at"] = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

            stmt = text("INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2) values (1, 2)")

            con.execute(stmt, parameters=new_row)
            con.commit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with engine_str.connect() as con:
        serials = pandas.read_sql("""SELECT * FROM lamp_contract_dn
            WHERE contract_hdr_status in ('Active', 'Expired') AND 
            serial_no IS NOT NULL AND product_id IS NOT NULL""", con, chunksize=100)

        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.map(process_chunk, serials)
```

Note 2 different engine configurations. This is necessary, because engine_str is streaming the results AKA using remote cursor. If I try to reuse the same engine for writing, I seem to be getting "declARE "c_11396e790_1" CURSOR WITHOUT HOLD FOR" error.

I think engine_str is not carried over to child processes, because child processes use completely different engine. I have tried disposing of the engine as an initializer for ProcessPoolExecutor() and I had the same issue. See the code below.

```
def initializer():
    engine.dispose(False)

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(initializer=initializer) as executor:
            executor.map(process_chunk, serials)
```

My expectation was that the main process would only use as much memory as it is needed for next(serials)

Comment: Would it be too large amount of data to hold in ram to generate all inputs first to a list and then using PostGres bulk create to insert all rows to database? Otherwise you could also bulk create in parts of your iterator.

Comment: @vahvero Yeah the data I'm trying to stream is too large. Please elaborate on what you mean by bulk create in parts of my iterator. How is that going reduce memory consumption?

Comment: I mean that you could do a set of sized `N`, bulk create, and move on to next rather than trying this concurrency approach. Calling commit in a loop should be very expensive. This approach should have constant memory size.